# Use a Trendline Formula to Get Values for Any Given X with Excel

Tags: statistics

First off, is this question appropriate for this Stack Exchange? If not, I'll remove it.

Now to my question:

Is there an easy way to apply the trend line formula from a chart to any given X value in Excel?

For example, I want to get the Y value for a given X = $2,006.00. I've already taken the formula and retyped it out be:

=-0.000000000008*X^3 - 0.00000001*X^2 + 0.0003*X - 0.0029

I am continually making adjustments to the trend line by adding more data, and don't want to retype out the formula every time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that excel has built-in formulas for any type of trendline that you might use (i.e. you can use "linest()" if you had your chart options set for a linear trendline). Knowing this, you might just want to use the corresponding the function to get your Y values.

Another method might be figuring out the VBA code used to create charts and trendlines and then extracting what you need. The following might be a good reference: http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.excel.programming/browse_frm/thread/c28678590192d449?hl=en&rnum=2&prev=/groups%3Fhl%3Den%26q%3Dtrendline%2Bcoefficients%26meta%3Dgroup%253Dmicrosoft.public.excel.programming